# 'NgModuleInjector' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used " https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-social-login " for my application to integrate social media authentication and was working with angular2. Now am trying to use the same with angular4 but getting following error -

ERROR in .../angular2-social-login.module.ngfactory.ts (12,57): Property 'NgModuleInjector' does not exist on type 'typeof "../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory.'

Please look the image..

help me out to resolve this.

Thanks!